# Typo3 - Passing POST data from a viewer to a controller (not working)

Tags: post, model-view-controller, controller, typo3

I cannot pass a $_POST variable from a viewer to a method in the desired controller. Most online resources suggest that just defining the variable as exemplified below will work (provided the name of the $variable is the same as the name of the input in the form.

```php
public function processFormAction($myValue = '') {}
```

I also tried using getArguments within the action defined above, as below

```php
$myValue = $this->request->getArguments()['myValue'] ?? '';
```

This is how I defined the form:

```html
<form 
  action="{f:uri.action(action: 'search', controller: 'Books')}" 
  method="post"
>
```

I am trying to avoid manually handling the $_POST["myValue"] variable in the method; it is not the best practice, and I would benefit from Typo3's sanitisation instead. Plus, I want to learn how to do this properly. I know the POST variable is accessible from the action within the controller. I can var_dump it. However, if I var_dump $myValue, I get nothing.

Is there any additional mapping or anything one must do to get the method to recognise the post variable?

I am new to MVC.

Comment: Resolved:

Problem solved.

**Viewer:**

    <f:form action='filter' object="Services" objectName="services">
        <f:form.submit value="Search" class="btn btn-primary"  />
        <f:form.textfield property="keyword" class="form-control" id="keyword" />
    </f:form>


**Controller:**

    public function filterAction(): \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface
    {
        $keyword = $this->request->getArguments()["services"]["keyword"];
        // More logic goes here.
        return $this->htmlResponse();
    }

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use <f:form> for the form, plus <f:form.input> and the likes to transfer your form data. All fields need a special plugin prefix so extbase can do it's magic, like also creating a hmac security conteol that lists all allowed variables to be transferred.

Comment: This form does pass $_POST data to the controller but I cannot pick up the keyword.

    <f:form action='filter' object="Services" objectName="services">
        <f:form.textfield property="keyword" />
        <f:form.submit value="Send" />
    </f:form>

Comment: You should specify method="POST" to be sure, and also you need to pass your input object as a variable, not reference, i.e: object="{Services}". The object needs to be instantiated in your Controller and assigned to the fluid template.